# Django REST API/AngularJS Application

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

So I am building a web tool using Django REST API and Angular JS. I have CSRF protection built into the bootstrapped template. My question is, do I have to do server validation of the `POST` information when submitted on a form?

I am used to doing all the validation server side, but with the CSRF stuff and how the REST API works, I don't know if I need to? For instance if I want to validate that a piece of the form is only alphanumeric etc to prevent injections and such.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does a pretty good job when it comes to validation, so SQL injection shouldn't be your concern as long as you don't write raw queries - [see here for more explanations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection).

However, if you have specific validation that you want and that is not enforced by django (such as not allowing a user to have a password length smaller than 8), you should definitely do it on the server side, even if you are already doing it in Angular.